# how to show sheet title in story in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, worksheet

I've created a story in Tableau 8.2. For one of my points I'm dragging in a worksheet, however when I do this, the worksheet title does not show up in the story point.

Is there any way to get the worksheet title to show in the story point when a worksheet is added to a story point?  Or do I need to manually add a description?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is an on-going issue with Tableau. A workaround will be to put the worksheet first into a dashboard and then drag the dashboard into the Story.

Dashboards give you much more control over formatting than worksheets. For anything with more than a little formatting effort, it is usually a good idea to wrap your worksheets in a dashboard before placing into a story.